# Bash prompt keeps disappearing

Tags: bash, ssh, prompt

I have a weird issue where my Bash prompt often completely disappears on a backspace. Doesn't make any sense to me, but it happens often:

[image]
[image]

I can't really think of why this is happening. Am I overlooking some configuration file or something?

Here's my `PS1` prompt:

```
PS1='\[\e]2;\u@\h\a\u@\h \W \$ '
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your `$PS1`.  Otherwise my blind guess is you may not have it wrapped in `\[ \]`.

Comment: Posted: `PS1='\[\e]2;\u@\h\a\u@\h \w \$ '`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with that PS1.  Type a few characters, backspace over them and whoosh, there it goes.

Comment: What does that PS1 accomplish that `PS1='\u@\h \W \$'` doesn't?

Comment: Writing `username@host` into the actual shell title.

Comment: Ah.  Here is the one I've used for a number of years.  I forget exactly how I developed it: PS1="\033]1;\u@\h\007\033]2;\u@\h : \w\007\033[99;1H\033[1A\n\h:\w> "

Comment: It appears you can change the \033 to \e in all cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I suspected in my comment, you are missing a `\]` in your `PS1`.  Try this one:

```
PS1='\[\e]2;\u@\h\a\]\u@\h \W \$ '
```

For comparison, the original is

```
PS1='\[\e]2;\u@\h\a\u@\h \W \$ '
#                  ^ missing \]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if something running is blanking your `PS1` env variable.
As an example on another machine not affected by that problem if you run

```
PS1=""
```

in a bash shell you will get the same output of your screen-shots.