# New bash prompt causing issues

Tags: bash, prompt

I changed my bash prompt to this:

```
PS1="\[\033[1;31m[\[\033[1;33m\$(date +%H:%M)\[\033[1;31m] \u:\[\033[1;32m\W\[\033[1;37m\$\[\033[0m\] "
```

Sorry for the long line, it is mostly due to colors. Basically when I hit the up arrow to go back in Bash history the prompt disappears and everything screws up.
It is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/bash-prompt-keeps-disappearing) but I don't know if a `\[`
 is missing and where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's clean it up a bit and make it more portable.  In general, it's best to use `tput` to generate the control sequences instead of hard coding them, as described in [Bash FAQ 53](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053?highlight=%28tput%29).  This way it is much easier to find your missing `\]`.

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
PS1="\[$red\][\[$yellow\]\A\[$red\]] \u:\[$green\]\W\[$white\]\$\[$reset\] "
```

Note that I replaced your `date` invocation with the built-in prompt escape `\A` that displays the same thing (24-hour time in `HH:MM` format).

There is one caveat with this approach as described in the linked Bash FAQ, where the output would be garbled if any of the `tput` control sequences output something that happened to contain a prompt escape.  I have never run into that issue so I generally ignore it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know of `tput`. This way everything is more clear and readable. Thanks!

Comment: Wow it works very well. I just added `bold_style=$(tput bold)` and `\[$bold_style\]` at the start of the string to make everything bold like in my question.

Answer (score 4):

You have unbalanced your `\[` and `\]`'s. Control sequences need to be wrapped in them, so that bash knows they don't actually occupy any space in your terminal.

Try this:

```
PS1="\[\033[1;31m\][\[\033[1;33m\]\$(date +%H:%M)\[\033[1;31m\]] \u:\[\033[1;32m\]\W\[\033[1;37m\]\$\[\033[0m\] "
```

[@jw013's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45484/20868) is even better, though, as it's much cleaner.

Comment: Oh I hadn't understood that every control sequence needed to be wrapped like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [ASCII table](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) has a reference of colors, bold, italic, and etc.