# Backspace deletes Bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I recently modified my Bash prompt via the `$PS1` variable so that I could have color. It is in my `.bashrc` file:

```
PS1="\\[\e[0;32m[\h::\W] >>\e[m "
```

Now if I type something and then have to backspace to clear it the entire prompt disappears. If I hit enter a new one shows up.

Looking at [this question regarding the same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/bash-prompt-keeps-disappearing) it would appear that I am missing a closing bracket. I don't know where it would go, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first I thought that the backslashes would self-escape within the double-quotes and that was the problem, but, on second-thought, `"\\["` is equivalent to `'\['` so this is not the case - it would have worked that way.

But the real problem was that `readline` did not know how many characters had been drawn to the screen and how many were intercepted as terminal escapes. In fact, it likely thought *no* prompt had been printed at all because your prompt consisted of what was essentially an open-quoted string.

So, as I noted in the comment, you needed to close the sequence. The `\[` means begin non-printing escape sequence in the prompt - it's so `readline` can keep track of how many chars are drawn on the screen. You also need to end it like:

```
PS1='\[non-printing terminal escapes here\]' 

man bash 2>/dev/null | grep '^ *\\\[' -A5

\[     begin  a  sequence  of   non-printing
       characters,  which  could  be used to
       embed  a  terminal  control  sequence
       into the prompt
\]     end  a sequence of non-printing char‐
       acters
```

Comment: @theillien: not sure, but I think `PS1='\[\e[0;32m[\h::\W] >>\e[\]m '` might not be right. Youu may still be off in the count though you likely won't notice until you start doing some prompt redraws - like for newlines in `$PS2` or so. I think this is safer `PS1='\[\e[0;32m\][\h::\W] >>\[\e[m\] '` - see how the `\e` bits are enclosed in the `\[...\]` quoted portion, but the printing bits - even the `bash` specific escapes are *not* enclosed. `readline` needs to know what bits are intercepted by the terminal - like color escapes - and what bits actually make it on the screen. Hence `\[...\]`

Comment: I have seen the newline issue that you mentioned. Instead of continuing a command onto a new line it begins to overwrite the line on which it started. I've replaced it with your suggestion. We'll see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What threw me off was the ```\[``` is what needs to be closed with ```\]``` versus the ```[``` which is part of the ANSI sequence.  For example ```\e[31;1m``` for bright red.  The ANSI sequence is within the bounding brackets ```\[ ... \]``` and its internal ```[``` does NOT get a closing ```]``` or ```\]``` bracket.  Hopes this helps someone, even though it's 5 years later.  (If I found it hopefully this will help someone else too.)